# How to change format to standard time JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a date string in JavaScript which is arranged in a particular manner. How do I rearrange this in order to fit standard time?

```js
let date = "2020-06-01T00:00:00Z"
```

How do I rearrange the `date` variable in order to match the format MM/DD, YYYY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to as follows:

```
  let date = "2020-06-01T00:00:00Z";
  date = new Date(date);
  var dd = date.getDate(); 
  var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear(); 
  if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} 
  if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm};
  console.log(mm+'/'+dd+', '+yyyy)
```

Comment: @hiphopfeels FYI, notice that while the date string is in UTC timezone, the getDate, getMonth, and getFullYear methods return values in the computer's local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

i don't real know this is possible but i found the function you can use instead

```js
function GetFormattedDate() {
  var todayTime = new Date();
  var month = todayTime.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = todayTime.getDate();
  var year = todayTime.getFullYear();
  return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
console.log(GetFormattedDate());
```

so you can add more in the function or edit what the function will return as a format according to your will